# Word VBA - How to get horizontal position with tab stops?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to parse a number of word documents (which were previously exported from a pdf document), for a total of 2000+ rows.

To extract data I'm using Regex without any problem but one: the currency fields could be **withdraw** or **deposit** (it's a bank account balance) and the only difference between them is their **horizontal position** (cannot unfortunately speak about column as it's not formatted like a table).

**I'm asking you for ideas how to detect whether they are withdraw or deposit.**

My rough idea is:

- get from word the tabs positions using `doc.Paragraphs.TabStops`
- get how many tabs characters there are after the second date. But how?
- calculate the length of currency characters and thus the position at the right side of currency (they're aligned on the right). But again how?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits to @[slightly snarky], I solved this way. I'm posting it as there are minor differences in the property: I had to collapse first.

```
Set oFound = r.Range  'where r is the searched paragraph
With oFound.Find
    .Text = ",^#^#"  'searching for the first amount, which ends with comma and two digits
    .MatchCase = False
    .ClearFormatting
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .Forward = True
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .Execute
End With
oFound.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
Debug.Print oFound.Information(wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage)
```

Answer (score 2):

One possibility:

Get the Word.Range of the first amount (non-date) in the line/paragraph, and use

```
TheRange.End.Information(wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage)
```

to work out which column they are in (there will probably be some variation even within each column)